# Using variable with SQL WHERE IN statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, where-clause

I would like to have the list of nodes set at the top of the script, then check if they are in the table.
The following code does not throw errors, but the logic is not working. It does not print the message when one of the nodes in the list exists.

```
DECLARE @nodeId nvarchar(50)
SET @nodeId = 'SomeNodeID, SomeOtherNodeID'
IF EXISTS (SELECT NodeId FROM dbo.tblNodeMaster WHERE NodeId in (@nodeId))
BEGIN
    PRINT RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(30), GETDATE())) + '  node exists.'
    RETURN
END
```

Using the following code without a variable it works fine. It will print the message when any node in the list exists.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT NodeId FROM dbo.tblNodeMaster WHERE NodeId in ('SomeNodeID', 'SomeOtherNodeID'))
BEGIN
    PRINT RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(30), GETDATE())) + '  node exists.'
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: You can't use `in` in that way with a string - it's a `set` operation, it doesn't parse the string.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server? (The above code is very product specific.)

Comment: Yes MS SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a string, you could use a `table variable`

```
    Declare @NodeId table (NodeId varchar(30))
    insert into @NodeId
    select 'SomeNodeID' union all select 'SomeOtherNodeID'
    
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tblNodeMaster WHERE NodeId in (select NodeId from @nodeId))
...
```

Comment: So, I actually have the NodeIDs in a data file. So I just loaded them into a temp table and used that. Thanks for help!

Comment: Ever heard of `values('SomeNodeID', 'SomeOtherNodeID')`

Comment: Haha yes - force of habbit I guess.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @nodeId nvarchar(50) = 'SomeNodeID,SomeOtherNodeID'
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tblNodeMaster WHERE NodeId IN (SELECT LTRIM(value) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@nodeId, ','))
BEGIN
    PRINT RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(30), GETDATE())) + '  node exists.'
    RETURN
END
```

You can use STRING_SPLIT as a sub-query to the IN operator.